# How can I change the default line spacing for Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

For every new Google Docs I would like to change the line spacing to 1.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Add titles, headings and customize the style of your document - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/116338?hl=en)

> ## Customize titles, subtitles, headings and text style
>
> With styles, you
> can quickly customize the look of text in a Google document. Use the
> new styles toolbar menu to format text in your document.
>
> 1. Highlight a selection of text with the font size and style that you'd
>    like to use for normal text or a particular heading.
> 2. Go to the styles
>    toolbar menu, and click the arrow next to **Normal text** or **Heading 1-6**.
>    [image: Styles dropdown]
> 3. Select Update **Heading X to match selection**.
> 4. All of the text in your document with the same text type, such as Heading 4 or Normal text, will be updated to match the font and font size of your initial selection.
>
> ### Normal text
>
> Normal text is the default text style of your document. If you update
> the style of normal text from the styles toolbar menu, the default
> text style of your document will change accordingly.
>
> If you change the font style of normal text, the font style of the
> headings will update. If you want your headings to have a different
> font style than normal text, we recommend setting normal text style
> prior to setting heading text style.
>
> ## Save default styles for your documents You can save customized styles to be used by default for new documents.
>
> 1. Expand the styles drop-down menu.
> 2. Point your mouse to Options.
> 3. Select Save as my default styles.
>
> Then, apply that style to a new document:
>
> 1. Expand the styles drop-down menu.
> 2. Point your mouse to Options.
> 3. Select Use my default styles.
>
> To restore your default styles to the default Google document styles:
>
> 1. Follow Steps 1 and 2 above.
> 2. Select Reset styles.

**References**
[Edit and format a Google document - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1663349?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** As Rubén points out, there is a way to set default line spacing, but here are two other ways as well.

1. You can create a blank document with the line spacing already changed, and just copy that Doc instead of creating a new one.
2. You can submit a template with the line spacing you want, and then create from a new template instead of from a new Doc.

Answer (score 0):

After searching in the official Google Doc Help documents it looks like that they don't have any option for default text formatting.

You may try searching for Google Docs add-ons that might help you set a default line spacing value for every doc you create, alternatively you may create your own Docs add-on to have it work as you need and use it by default, though the process of creating an add-on might be very difficult if you are not experienced in JavaScript programming.