# Change the page color of a Google doc?

Tags: google-docs

Is it possible to make the page black? (I'd then color the text white/colored.)

I love the Atom text editor by the people at Github, so this is taking a cue from them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files > Page setup...

[image: File menu]

[image: Page setup menu]

then choose "Page color".

[image: Color chooser]

[image: Page setup menu after choosing color background]

[image: White text on a black page background]

Comment: Excellent. Are there templates? I'd make all the text white, but I don't want to have to change all my links back to being blue manually.

Comment: There's the "Set as default" button on the Page setup dialog. See also [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79857/354) about setting the text style defaults.